# Kafka reactor consumer API

Tags: project-reactor, spring-kafka

I need to implement retry feature in kafka consumer. I am using spring reactor api.

Flux> inboundFlux = KafkaReceiver.create(receiverOptions).receive();

```
    inboundFlux.subscribe(r -> {
        if (accept(r)) {
            r.receiverOffset().acknowledge();
        }
    }, this::errorOut);
```

The retry option on inboundFlux.retry() is not working. Please suggest how do I make this work.

Comment: What are the symptoms that you decided it doesn’t work?

Comment: How do I make sure it calls accept() again after retry?